# how to get file relative path with pythons os - django python

Tags: python, django

I am getting all file names under directory `dir`:

```
files = os.listdir(dir)
```

and after rendering file names to template, i am showing them in template like this:

```
{% for each in files %}
<li>
  <a href="{{each}}" target="_blank">{{each}}</a>
<li>
{% endfor %}
```

I want that If i click on filename, the file should be opened in new window. but here the problem is that `files = os.listdir(dir)` returns only file names and not its relative path. how do i get the path also?

Comment: can you send the path to the template in another variable? ...
`<a href="{{path}}/{{each}}" ...`

Comment: Are you looking for os.getcwd()?

Comment: @jcfollower, how to get the path is my problem now. i am able to get absolute path with ``C://...`` but i need the relative path

Comment: Once you have the absolute path, can't you just use the last part of it as the relative path?

Comment: @jcfollower, absolutely! :D totally right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a '/' to tell the browser to start from the site's root. Also, opening the link in a new window should be HTML:

```
<a href="/{{each}}" target="_blank">{{each}}</a>
```

Edit:

```
files = [os.path.join(dir, f) for f in files]
```

Comment: thanks, but {{each}} is filename, i need to get the path of those files, any idea?

Comment: @doniyor I added that to the response

Comment: Thanks, but this gives the absolute path, absolute path gives some errors in chrome etc... how can i get the relative path so that i can open it?

Comment: @doniyor relative to start_dir would be os.path.relpath(os.path.join(dir, f), start=start_dir)